# sendmail not sending to (or qmail not receiving from) the same machine

Tags: php, email

A web applications sends two emails:

1. to the user of the webapp
2. to the administrator

the administrators mailbox (`qmail`) is on the same machine as the web application (`php`, `apache`, `/usr/sbin/sendmail`).

email 1 works, email 2 *sometimes* doesn't work. I don't see any pattern in the mails that don't work. Also because I don't exactly know WHICH emails failed (since the email itself would be the only notification).

email 2 looks like this:

```
from: <username@userdomain.tld> #changes for each user
to: <admin@webapp-domain.com>
```

What could be the problem?

Are `rejected` emails stored somewhere? (if they are rejected.. how do I check this?)

Answer (score 1):

you have to look in the logs to see what's happening behind the scene...

- for qmail-smtpd look into: /var/log/qmail/smtpd/current
- for qmail look into: /var/log/qmail/current

that should guide you towards where do you need to take a look